# Run xcode_backend.sh script file throws Unhandled exception

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I want to add my Flutter module into my iOS native project, When I add xcode_backend.sh file's path in Xcode Build Phases:
"/opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build
"/opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" embed

just build it Xcode throws a error like this:

Unhandled exception:
Exception: Command "rsync -av --delete --filter - .DS_Store /Users/yh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeWithFlutter-cxdjpuhxjaevbhakypgxzehxmlzn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.framework /Users/yh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeWithFlutter-cxdjpuhxjaevbhakypgxzehxmlzn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativeWithFlutter.app/Frameworks" exited with code 23
#0      Context.runSync (file:///opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:105:7)
#1      Context.embedFlutterFrameworks (file:///opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:190:5)
#2      Context.run (file:///opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:57:9)
#3      main (file:///opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:17:5)
#4      _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:32)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I think the file's path is correct, and what's wrong with it?
anybody can help me?